# Erlang Erl commands not working on Windows 10

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erl

Hello i was trying to issue some distributed erlang commands such as `erl -sname`/`erl -name` and i do not get a response.

If i put `.` at the end it says syntax error.
If i don't it won't return anything and it will treat it like an unfinished command.

I thought this is only for these commands but it seems there are others that will not do anything like 
`erl -man <module_name>`.

Do i need to set something up to be able to issue `erl` commands.

**P.S** OS is `Windows 10`.

Comment: Are you trying to run `erl -sname` from within the erlang shell, that is, after already having started `erl` without an `-sname` option? That does not work.

Comment: You should display the exact command and the return messages. I use erl with windows 10 and it works very well. You must complete all your command with a dot, for example: `pwd().` . If you forgot it type a single dot and return on the next line. Don't type the command again, the shell is waiting for this dot to start the command analysis. In my example, If you type the command again, the shell will try to interpret `pwd() pwd().` and thus will issue a syntax error.

Comment: @RichardC i just opened a erlang shell and type the `erl -sname`/`erl name` like i do with other commands that work like :`node()` or `pwd()` or `cd`

Answer (score 0):

The `erl` command (with or without `-sname`) is simply how you run Erlang from a console window like cmd or powershell. On Windows, to get a fully working Erlang shell with command line editing etc, you need to use the special `werl` executable instead of `erl` - this is due to how Windows consoles work. Try opening a cmd or powershell windows and see how it works.

If you open the properties of the icon you have used for starting Erlang, you will see that the command it is running is `werl` (from the Start menu you have to use "more -> open file path" to find the actual icon first). You can edit this and add options like `-sname yournodename` to the command, or you can create a copy of the icon (e.g. to your desktop) and give it a more suitable name, like "My Erlang node", and then edit its options.

Comment: You are right i have been using `werl` so far until now.I have issued commands , loaded modules , running them without problem. What i do not understand is what do i have to do to be able to run commands like `sname` , `net_adm:ping` . If i run them like `[command].` it says syntax error.

Comment: You cannot run a console (cmd) command in the Erlang shell. Only Erlang expressions. The -sname option has to be given to the erl/werl command when the system starts. It is however possible to start the Erlang networking afterwards by writing `net_kernel:start([mynodename, shortnames]).`.